# Can I install impala on hadoop-2.7.2 and apache-hive-1.2.1?

Tags: hadoop, impala

On Internet there are many documents about installing impala on CHD, but my hadoop is Apache hadoop instead of CHD, I have tried impala-2.5.0+cdh5.7.2 on Apache hadoop (hadoop-2.7.2) but faild at last. If I want to install impala, which impala version is suitable for me? Or I need to re-install a new CHD system.

Comment: 1. the Cloudera distro is *CDH*, not CHD // 2. if you don't explain how your installation *"failed at last"* then you have a very small chance of getting help.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to know that if there is any impala version suitable for apache hadoop 2.7.2, and any pactice for that. (I know there are lots of material about impala on CDH )